# How to add Custom UIView on UITableViewCell Swipe in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to add custom UIView on `UITableViewCell` Swipe. Basically I want to add two `UIButton`, one on top and other just below it. Both having height half of cell. If I use `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of `UITableView` that this add `UIButton` side by side but i want to add buttons on top having height equal to half of table view cell and other just below it having same height.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can add this code in your custom tableview cell:

```
var topBtn = UIButton()
var behindBtn = UIButton()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    awakeFromNib()
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    topBtn.setTitle("top", for: .normal)
    topBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    addSubview(topBtn)

    behindBtn.setTitle("behind", for: .normal)
    behindBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    addSubview(behindBtn)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let btnH = self.frame.size.height/2
    let btnW = self.frame.size.width

    topBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: btnW, height: btnH)
    behindBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: btnH, width: btnW, height: btnH)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

and this is the result:
[image]

Comment: please read question correctly, i basically want this feature when user swipe cell.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a view, which contains two buttons and appears on swipe event? If I clearly got a question you can add this view on UITableViewCell, hide it and set hidden = NO on swipe event. Also you may use UIPanGestureRecognizer and setting the views alpha. Or change the frame, in this case would be better to set cell.clipsToBounds = YES

Answer (score -1):

You can start by implementing this method:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // you need to implement this method too or you can't swipe to display the actions
}
```

Then you can customize it by adding two buttons in a view as you want it to and returning that view in your `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method.